# Two versions of Talend giving different results

Tags: java, talend

I have a Talend job that runs fine on my machine but gives incorrect results on a colleague's computer. I have Talend 6.1 and Java 8 (update 181). The other person has Talend 7.1.1 and Java 8 (update 191).

The difference is in a tMap that joins 5 data streams. As I say, it all works correctly for me. But the other person's set up gives a final result that (probably) implies one of the joins does not work.

Can you suggest what's changed in Talend that might affect this?

Although it is rather hard to pull it apart to isolate which join is problematic, the most likely candidate is this one:

[image]

The code in that join is this:

```
(Church.Name == null || Church.Name.length() == 0 
|| Church.Denomination__c == null || Church.Denomination__c.length() == 0)
    ? ""
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("ANGLICAN")
    ? "Anglican"
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("APOSTOLIC")
    ? "Apostolic"
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("Catholic")
    ? "Catholic"
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("CHURCHES OF CHRIST")
    ? "Church of Christ"
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("CHURCH OF CHRIST")
    ? "Church of Christ"
: Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("UNITING")
    ? "Uniting Church of Australia"
: Church.Denomination__c
```

**Later edit**: In order to test further, I replaced that complex code so that the join is now a simple link using `Church.Denomination__c` in one table to match the key field in the next table. The same problem continues: works on my machine with Talend 6.1 but not on my colleague's machine with Talend 7.1. On his machine, the join in question never finds any matches (and hence passes a null value on to the next join). As I noted in a comment, we have double-checked that the data input to the tMap are the same on both machines, and that the join parameters in the tMap are the same on both machines.

FWIW, the job was created on my machine with Talend 6.1. I exported the whole job, my colleague imported the job into his Talend 7.1. Both run without any error messages, but give different results.

Comment: This is incorrect: `Church.Denomination__c.toUpperCase().contains("Catholic")`.  An uppercased string can *never* contain `"Catholic"`.

Comment: Haha! obvious mistake! But that is not the cause of the problem -- doesn't explain differing results across two machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. The discrepancy was caused by the two versions of the Talend job *not* being identical. My colleague had edited part of the job prior to this tMap.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the join settings (in your 'Denom' table, click on the icon on the right of the panel) are the same : between talend versions, default behaviour is not the same I think (Unique match/all matches/all the lines)

Comment: Nice suggestion but the settings are the same on both machines. All the joins on both machines have the settings Load Once, Unique Match, Left Outer Join, false.